# How do I fix "Unable to find an entry point named 'x' in DLL 'y' "

Tags: c#, c++

I have spent at least 3 hours trying to figure out why this wont work. Some background is that i'm trying to improve my coding skills in both c# and c++ by coding some hacks for a game called Assault Cube. I'm trying to call functions from c# from my c++ dll.

My C# Code:

```
        [DllImport("CortexAPI.dll")]
        static extern void gameCheck();
```

My C++ Code:

```
class cortexFunctions{

        __declspec(dllexport) static void gameCheck()
        {
            /*finds ac window*/
            string AC = "ac_client.exe";

            std::wstring convertac = std::wstring(AC.begin(), AC.end());/*plz find out how to do this without converting :)*/
            LPCWSTR assaultcube = convertac.c_str();

            HWND assaultclient = FindWindow(0, assaultcube);
            /*end of finding ac client*/

            /*If assault cube is open, then outputs that the exploit is working fine*/
            if (assaultclient == 0) {
                MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Assault Cube is not open."), TEXT("Open Assault Cube"), 0);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Cortex is working fine!"), TEXT("Good!"), 0);
            }
        }
    };
```

Please I have tried so many different solutions but they always either dont work or lead to another issue.

Comment: Not my forte (its been a long time), however its likely name mangling. either use extern "C" or view the dll in a dependency walker, and you will see the name is likely not gameCheck

Comment: hrm on second thoughts, C++ method is static, which will likely cause issues as well

Comment: What do you get with https://www.dependencywalker.com/ ? Also, your C# side needs to declare the calling convention `Cdecl`